# Why does my model disappear as I get closer?

Tags: unity

[image]

As I get closer, the model I made disappears. how can i fix this situation?

Comment: we would need to see a bit more of your camera settings and the object in question to give you an answer

Comment: You may also want to try selecting the object and pressing `F` to focus the scene view camera on that object - this will also adjust the camera's near plane accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. **Scene Camera** > "Uncheck **Dynamic Clipping**".